# Open bookmarks in new tab

Tags: windows, bookmarks, opera

Is there a way to always open bookmarks in a new tab in Opera?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have it so that all bookmarks open up in new tabs by setting it in your preferences:

> Tools > Preferences > Advanced > Tabs

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image: Opera tabs]

Then uncheck **Reuse current tab**.

To be double sure, click on **Additional tab options...**.

[image: windows instead of tabs]

Make sure that **Open windows instead of tabs** is also unchecked.

Click **OK** to save the changes.

Now, when you open a bookmark, or a favourite from the Personal Bar, it will open up in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Opera but in Chrome (and I think Firefox) you can open bookmarks in a new tab by clicking on them with the scroll button.

Maybe it works in Opera as well?

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Opera.

Comment: This works in every single browser. The only thing that might differ is whether the tab opens next to the current one, or at the end of the line of already opened tabs.

Comment: I sure hope it does work in Opera, it's a feature I can't live without.

Comment: This works for links, but not for bookmarks.

Comment: In fact, it works with the actual bookmarks (from the bookmark panel on side), but it doesn't work for the bookmarks from the "personal bar", simply (and yes, this is annoying... this personal bar in Opera is the only thing I prefer in other browsers...)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Opera either, but in Firefox and Chrome you can click any link/bookmark while holding CTRL to open it in a new tab.

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Opera

Comment: It's working for me in Opera 9.64