# Can I open new tabs in Opera with a homepage loaded rather than empty?

Tags: tabs, opera

By default opera opens new tabs empty. Can I configure it so that upon opening a new tab the homepage is automatically loaded?

Comment: Actually, by default, Opera tabs come with the Speed Dial, if I remember well (or this is to activate, maybe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, set your Home page, which can be done via:

> Tools > Preferences > General

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> and then to the General tab.

Next, [set all your bookmarks to open up in new tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/27244/open-bookmarks-in-new-tab/).

Now, call home with the home shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.

This will fire up a new tab set to your home page and skip showing the Speed Dial/blank tab.

Comment: Neat trick. Upside-down solution, I haven't thought of that.

Comment: If you were in space, it'd be right-side up.

Answer (score 4):

Kadłubowski & Rads: Yes, you can tell Opera to [open a new tab with your home page instead of the speeddial](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/how-to-open-new-tab-with-homepage-in-opera). Short summary; You can modify the keyboard shortcut and mouse gesture to do exactly what you want.

Comment: that link is dead