# How do I make the "New Tab" page set as my homepage in Opera?

Tags: opera, homepage

How do I make the "New Tab" page set as my homepage in Opera? (as in when I load up Opera it opens new tab page)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want Speed Dial (the page that appears when you open up a "New Tab") as your homepage.

If this is the case, go to `Preferences (Ctrl-F12) > General > Startup > Start with Speed Dial`. Otherwise, there are other Startup or homepage settings that you might prefer (Show start-up dialog, Start with home page, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a question titled: [Can I open new tabs in Opera with a homepage loaded rather than empty](https://superuser.com/questions/32789/can-i-open-new-tabs-in-opera-with-a-homepage-loaded-rather-than-empty). Is that what you are trying to do ?

**EDIT**

If you want to set the speed dial follow the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/set-the-speed-dial-as-the-opera-startup-page/).

- Tools \ Preferences - General tab - Select "Start with blank page" in Startup drop-down.
- Click Advanced \ Tabs - Click "Additional tab options". Make sure **Allow window with no tabs** is unchecked.

That should do it.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment. Regards,

Comment: No, what is happening is when I open up Opera, what comes up is what was on there when I exited Opera. What I want to happen is when I open Opera I want the "Speed Dial" or "New Tab" page to come up.

Answer (score 1):

Opera browser is originally configured to show the "speed dial" tab as the default home page.If you clicked on "new tab" which is symbolized by (+) sign you will get the same "speed dial" tab and it will not give you a blank tab.So you can configure the home page or the action of starting the program in Opera by clicking on Menu>Settings>preferences and choose the best option you like.

Answer (score 1):

you can set opera to always load the last autopera.win file
thus giving you a window with an empty tab
and set speed dial state in preferences ( opera:config) to 3
i highly recommend reading tamils blog on opera
http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/