# How do I make the "New Tab" page set as my homepage in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, speed-dial

Like the post from @Bama Joe 411 ([How do I make the “New Tab” page set as my homepage in Opera?](https://superuser.com/questions/299366/how-do-i-make-the-new-tab-page-set-as-my-homepage-in-opera)) I'd like to know how to set Firefox 13's new tab page (speed dial) as the default homepage to open after firefox has been started.

Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your homepage to `about:newtab`

Comment: Great!!! Thx a lot!